# URL Connection giving certificate path error

Tags: java, ssl, httpurlconnection

Wile i am trying to connect a `https` is giving certificate error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.setProxiedClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:142)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.setProxiedClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:118)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:629)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1320)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>     at com.poc.TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:75)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
>     ... 33 more Caused by:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
>     at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
>     ... 39 more

Connection is simple https connection

Comment: Try http://www.jyothis.co.in/2011/11/12/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception/

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the HTTPS certificate to your JVM. To get the certificate from the HTTPS, go through a browser, then click on the "lock" logo on the address bar. You should be able to export the certificate.

Solution for Linux:
In `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`, use this command:

```
sudo keytool -import -alias keyName -file /[pathForYourKey]/keyName.cert -keystore cacerts
```

Default password for "cacerts" is `changeit`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but can you please provide solution in windows

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Windows, so I do not know how to do that. Maybe this can help you: http://certificate.fyicenter.com/124_Java_VM_Adding_Trusted_Certificates_for_Java_on_Windows.html